# Как пересечь элементы списков?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим, есть список `a`, состоящий из:

```
['Зелёный','грустный','Красный','Весёлый'],['Синий','Оранжевый','Белый','Чёрный','Серый']
```

Каким образом я могу сделать так, чтобы получился список:

```
`['зелёный синий', 'зелёный оранжевый', 'зелёный белый', 'зелёный чёрный', 'зелёный серый', 'грустный синий','грустный оранжевый','грустный белый' и т.д]`
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import product

a = ['Зелёный', 'Грустный', 'Красный', 'Весёлый']
b = ['Синий', 'Оранжевый', 'Белый', 'Чёрный', 'Серый']

c = [' '.join(i) for i in product(a, b)]
```

Ну или без импорта

```
c = ['{} {}'.format(x, y) for x in a for y in b]
```

Comment: А если a и b являются списка `a`?Т.е. [[a],[b]]

Comment: `['{} {}'.format(x, y) for x in a[0] for y in a[1]]`

Comment: `['К к', 'К и', 'К т', 'К а', 'К й', 'К с', 'К к', 'К и', 'К е', 'и к', 'и и', 'и т', 'и а', 'и й', 'и с', 'и к', 'и и', 'и е', 'т к', 'т и', 'т т', 'т а', 'т й', 'т с', 'т к', 'т и', 'т е', 'а к', 'а и', 'а т', 'а а', 'а й', 'а с', 'а к', 'а и', 'а е', 'й к', 'й и', 'й т', 'й а', 'й й', 'й с', 'й к', 'й и', 'й е']`

Получается вот такое.

Comment: Всё работает как должно https://ideone.com/1iVSlu Вы что-то делаете не так.

Comment: Хм. И правда. А если таких списков 12, то просто продолжать в том же духе?

Comment: Да хоть 100, ничего принципиально не меняется - `print([' '.join(i) for i in product(*a)])`

Comment: А есть более экономный в плане памяти способ?